# Create share variable after combined groupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am having trouble describing my problem, so I'll jump right into it. Here is some test data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"family":["Smith","Miller","Simpson","Miller","Simpson","Smith","Miller","Simpson","Miller"],
                    "first_name":["Anna","Bart","Lisa","Ida","Paul","Bridget","Harry","Dustin","George"],
                    "shirt_color":["green","yellow","red","yellow","green","red","yellow","red","red"]})
```

Now I'd like to create a new column in my original dataframe that contains the share of shirt_color per family, so every row with e.g. family Miller and shirt_color yellow has the same value 0.75, etc..

I have tried several approaches, but did not succeed with any of them.

```
df = df.groupby("family").apply(lambda x: x.groupby("shirt_color").apply(lambda x: x.size()/familysize))
```

This seemed promising, but as you can see, I could not access the number of family members in the last lambda function any more. I also tried to create a groupby object of only family and iterate over the dataframes, grouping all dataframes by color individually, but somehow I could not manage to put the dataframes back to one in the end.

This doesn't seem to be a very exotic thing to do with a dataframe, so I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I'm out of ideas.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should avoid `apply` as this leads to an inefficient Python-level loop. Here's an alternative solution using `GroupBy` + `transform`:

```
f = df.groupby('family')['first_name'].transform('size')
g = df.groupby(['family', 'shirt_color'])['first_name'].transform('size')

df['ratio'] = g / f

print(df)

    family first_name shirt_color     ratio
0    Smith       Anna       green  0.500000
1   Miller       Bart      yellow  0.750000
2  Simpson       Lisa         red  0.666667
3   Miller        Ida      yellow  0.750000
4  Simpson       Paul       green  0.333333
5    Smith    Bridget         red  0.500000
6   Miller      Harry      yellow  0.750000
7  Simpson     Dustin         red  0.666667
8   Miller     George         red  0.250000
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.groupby('family').apply(lambda g: g.groupby("shirt_color").apply(lambda x: x.size/g.size)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Just use different variable names. By using both `x` you override your previous variable, and can't access it

```
df.groupby("family").apply(lambda s: s.groupby("shirt_color").apply(lambda x: x.size/s.size))

family   shirt_color
Miller   red            0.250000
         yellow         0.750000
Simpson  green          0.333333
         red            0.666667
Smith    green          0.500000
         red            0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `value_counts` and `merge`:

```
s = (df.groupby('family').shirt_color
        .value_counts(normalize=True).rename('ratio').reset_index())
```

```
    family shirt_color     ratio
0   Miller      yellow  0.750000
1   Miller         red  0.250000
2  Simpson         red  0.666667
3  Simpson       green  0.333333
4    Smith       green  0.500000
5    Smith         red  0.500000
```

To put this back into the initial DataFrame:

```
df.merge(s)
```

```
    family first_name shirt_color     ratio
0    Smith       Anna       green  0.500000
1   Miller       Bart      yellow  0.750000
2   Miller        Ida      yellow  0.750000
3   Miller      Harry      yellow  0.750000
4  Simpson       Lisa         red  0.666667
5  Simpson     Dustin         red  0.666667
6  Simpson       Paul       green  0.333333
7    Smith    Bridget         red  0.500000
8   Miller     George         red  0.250000
```

Comment: Never knew about `normalize=True`! +1